# How to check if data constitute a time series with simple moving average method?

Tags: time-series

I have some set of random data. I would like to check if this data constitute a time series. I know how to apply a simple moving average method to the data. But after applying it, how can I say if the data is time series or not?

Comment: You don't need a method to identify a time series. A definition is that you have observations in sequence for each of which you know the time of observation. Taking a moving average won't establish either way whether data are a time series: you need to know how the data were recorded.

Comment: @NickCox : Interesting. My teacher said, that I have to know if my data constitute a time series (if is statistically dependent and/or their statistical distributions are time-dependent) and that I can do it by applying a simple average method. I collected my data doing some measurements. I measured what I need to measure (did about 5 measurements), wrote down the results, and thats it. The interval beetween my measurements wasnt constant. How about that?

Comment: You've changed your question. You do have some idea of what "constitutes" a time series, so why you asked your question is unclear. You can't do much analysis with "about 5" measurements that are irregularly spaced.

Comment: Is this question perhaps a version of the one at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79838/simple-average-method-calculating-moving-average-and-moving-variance-how-can-i?

Answer (score 2):

Let me change the question a little. Let's suppose the question is "Can I treat this analytically as cross-sectional data, or do I need to treat it as time series data"?

If we ask it that way, the question is whether the observations are autocorrelated. So run an autocorrelation and see whether it is "large".  You have only five observations, so your estimate of autocorrelation isn't going to be precise. The irregular spacing causes problems as well, but if you find autocorrelation with irregularly spaced data you would likely find it with evenly spaced data.

As @NickCox notes, you can't do much with about 5 irregularly spaced data points.

Comment: So it cant be done with SMA method? What should I use instead? What autocorrelation method do you propose?

Comment: I was thinking about doing it this way: I can calculate SMA and write down the calculated average means, then I can compare the differences between the means, and if there is no difference, I can be sure that my data is stationary. For example: I have numbers = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and a window = 3, then average means are: 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 so the differences between them is always 1 (constant). (When I do avg[i+1]-agv[i] I always get 1 for my calculated means). So should I consider my dataset stationary?

Comment: No; a time series with linear trend (and in this case zero variability otherwise) is not stationary. Subtract the trend and it is.