# Simple Average Method, calculating moving average and moving variance, how can I say if stationary or not?

Tags: mean, measurement, stationarity

Lets say I have a sample data (here is just 10 numbers, in real I have about 10000 measurement results). Then, I want to check if the data is stationary or not using Simple Average Method. For example, my data set of size `N = 10`:

```
X = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0};
```

I calculated averages (window = 3):

```
SAM = {2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0}
```

with this formula:

```
(1+2+3)/3 = 2
(2+3+4)/3 = 3
(3+4+5)/3 = 4
...
```

and put them into SAM table above. Then, calculated the differences beetwen my averages, `SAM[i+1] = SAM[i]`, and I got a differences table: `1 1 1 1 1 1 1` from which I see that the difference between means (averages) is constant (its always 1).

Can I assume that with this simple test my data `X = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0};` is stationary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your first differences are constant then your data are *not* stationary, as the mean is increaing over time. Your first differences are indeed stationary with mean 1 variance 0.

With time series data, one of the most critical quesions is how to make the data stationary (one could argue this is the whole point of time series analysis). In practice this includes identifying trend, seasonality/cyclicality, stochastic drift, and autocorrelation. This will require more than the moving average can provide on its own.

However, you can probably use the moving average profitably if you want to get a rough confirmation that there  is no trend or periodicity. In this case, you are using the moving average as a smoothing device. You can simply regress your data vs time and see if the best fit line has a large slope, if not, then you don't have a strong linear trend. Also, if you don't notice any increases in spead about the line or any periodcity (ocillating values or tight clumps of data followed by disperse clouds of data) then you have confirmed that the first/second order trend and periodicity are not present to a large degree.

You will need more sophisticated tools to get any more quantitative. This is essentially a time series analysis, which is a whole field of statistics. A large part of that field is devoted to establishing and testing stationarity; therfore, I can't do it justice in this short space suffice it to say that yoru question has been heavily studies by researchers in time series analysis. See [this](http://www.cas.usf.edu/~cconnor/geolsoc/html/chapter11.pdf) for some basic background.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess I understood it wrong; I shall not take a look at the differences, but just on the calculated means = theyre not constant,as you noticed, theryre increasing; so my data isnt stationary, right? It has nothing to do with the differences?

Comment: @nullpointer correct

Comment: Just another question if you dont mind. So for my data to be stationary, my `SAM` table should look like this: `SAM = {9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0, 9.0}` (or something like that) - the point is, the moving average values should be constant, not their differences? (And I should check the same for the variance? Or just means are enough?)

Comment: @nullpointer if you have data with some randomness, then your SAM will not look quite that neat, but yes, you have the general idea. If you SAM appears to be wandering randomly about a roughly horizontal line, then its possible that its stationary. If its veering off ine a particualr direction or looks like a messy sine-wave, then you may want to recosider stationarity. Again, you need some more sophisticated(sometimes considerably so) tools to be more precise.

Comment: Ok, I see. Yes, Im trying to understand the general idea :) I guess with random data `SAM` could be `SAM = {9.2, 9.7, 9.3, 9.6, 9.4, 10.0, 9.1, 9.7}` (or something similar). Thank you again

Comment: @nullpointer exactly. The noisier your SAM data are, the less you will be able to make any determinations, but you have the general idea.

Comment: I hope this is the last question: should I do the same `moving` method test for my data, but with the variance instead of mean? I mean, having two tests: `moving average` and `moving variance` (where the variances should be equal too, same as the means) gives me more certainty of the stationarity of the data than just the `moving average` test alone?

Comment: @nullpointer yes, that would give you a more direct measurement of how the variability changes over time, subject to the same caveats as above.

Comment: I calculated the moving mean (its increasing) and the moving variance (its constant) for my example data set, `X`. And I came up with the new question: what can I say if the mean is increasing/decreasing and the variance is constant, or the opposite (the mean is constant, the variance is increasing/decreasing)? Is it a strong requirement that BOTH mean and the average MUST be constant? Or maybe its enough that the mean OR the variance is constant to be able to say my data are stationary? (For my example data mean is increasing, but the variance is constant, its about ~ 0.666667) Thanks!

Comment: @nullpointer technically each data point must have been drawn from the same distribution; therefore, all statistical measures should be the same. Your data are not stationary but the differences between successive  points may be stationary - I'd take a look at that.

Comment: are not stationary because of the non-constant means, right? But the variances are constant ... So I guess that I can say my data are stationary only when I have BOTH means and variances constant?

Comment: If some data are stationary then they all came from the same distribution.... Any deviation indicates some form of non stationarity exists... Your data are non stationary in the mean and stationary in the variance...