# How can I say if my data is a time series?

Tags: time-series, repeated-measures, measurement

I have some measurement results (about 10000 or even more). How can I say (which methods should I use and how to apply them) to check if my data is time series or is a statistical sample?

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79755/how-to-check-if-data-constitute-a-time-series-with-simple-moving-average-method As with that question, whether your data are time series is something that should be evident from the inclusion (or exclusion) of a time variable. If you are in doubt, you are not in a position to decide on appropriate analyses. On a different front, the distinction between a time series and a statistical sample makes no sense; a time series is also often a sample or thought of as such.

Comment: @NickCox: I guess (from the definition of time series) my measurement results are the time series - I measured something through some time, did more than one measurement, interval between the measurements wasnt constant but I think its not the problem. I think I should better ask how can I check if my data are statistically dependent and/or their statistical distributions are time-dependent?

Comment: If you need to use historical data points as possible predictors this is also an indication that your data is a time series. An ARIMA model is an optimized "moving-average modcel" as ARIMA can identify how many terms to use in your weighted moving average and precisely how to weihgh these terms rather than assuming them to be equal.

Comment: Did you record the time they were taken at? If not, then it is not a times-series at all (not to mention traditionally time series have even spaced measurement intervals, though one can interpolate too transform uneven spaced intervals into even). It sounds like you have repeated measures. Check out this R-Help post: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-June/200591.html

Comment: @TaylerJones: So if the interval between measurements isnt constant I cant say that my data are the time series?

Comment: @yak you can if you recorded a time variable, such as date and time of the observation. You could of also directly recorded the time since the last observation. You can then use an interpolation method to create even intervals and analyze it as a time series. You shouldn't get hung up on 'is my data a time series' so much as you should be concerned with 'can I use time series analysis methods with my data?' The answer to the latter is you can't without known time intervals (via known even intervals or a time variable)

Comment: Many time series methods can accommodate unevenly spaced data. They are just not well featured in introductory texts.